# Streamline web.config connectionString encryption

Tags: deployment, encryption, web-config

Is there a way to streamline the process of encrypting the connectionstrings after you deploy a web application?

Here's the backstory.  We manage many .NET websites.  We move them to a development server and then eventually up to the production server.  But after each site is created on the development box or the server box, I have to go onto the server and encrypt the sensitive data (usernames / passwords / connectionStrings).

This becomes tedious when you start talking hundreds of websites.  Is there a better way than doing it by hand?  Something that a developer who doesn't have access to Remote into the server could run after they deploy the application?

Or is this just wishful thinking?

Comment: How exactly are you encrypting those sections?

Comment: Through the command line using the aspnet_regiis tool.

Comment: Have you come up with something better in the year since you originally wrote this? Do share, if so!

Comment: Unfortunately not.  It seems Microsoft hasn't implemented an easy way to remotely do this.  :(

Comment: I would use deployment software (like Octopus for .NET), and then run a powershell script post deployment that would execute those commands for you.

Answer (score -4):

I would use deployment software (like Octopus for .NET), and then write a post deployment powershell script that would execute those commands for you.  Add that powershell script to the PostDeploy hook, and it should take care of that  (Most, if not all, mainstream deployment tools come with ways to execute commands after a deployment).